# Newtonsoft Json.NET serialized object not being rendered properly in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I am using ASP.NET MVC Razor View to serialize an object to JSON. The output is correct in the debugger, but because it escapes every quote I think MVC may be trying to encode it because the final output ends up like this:

```
{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Blowby&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:17},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;BlownInsert&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:11},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Blowout&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:13},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Contamination&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:7},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;CrushedInsert&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:3},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Reclaim&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:8},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;ShortShot&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:4},{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;Sinks&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:10}
```

The json format is exactly what I want, but instead of &quot it needs to actual quotes. I have tried HtmlUtilites.HtmlDecode() with no luck. How can I fix the output?

Here is more of the code being used if it helps, this is inside a .cshtml/Razor file.

```
 List<LightSwitchApplication.Models.GraphData> DonutGraphData = (List<LightSwitchApplication.Models.GraphData>)ViewData["DonutGraphData"];
string donutSerialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DonutGraphData);
```

And the GraphData Class:

```
namespace LightSwitchApplication.Models
{
public class GraphData
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }

    public GraphData(string label, int value)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

}

And the actual variable being output to the View:

```
if ($('#donut-graph').length) {
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'donut-graph',
                data: @donutSerialized,
                formatter: function (x) {
                    return x
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is the output of donutSerialized in the debugger:

```
"[{\"label\":\"Blowby\",\"value\":17},{\"label\":\"BlownInsert\",\"value\":11},{\"label\":\"Blowout\",\"value\":13},{\"label\":\"Contamination\",\"value\":7},{\"label\":\"CrushedInsert\",\"value\":3},{\"label\":\"Reclaim\",\"value\":8},{\"label\":\"ShortShot\",\"value\":4},{\"label\":\"Sinks\",\"value\":10}]"
```

Comment: How are you presenting this string?

Comment: where and how do you use the "final output" ?

Comment: It would really help if you could show us the code you're using.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added the code that I am using for this operation.

Comment: Can you show the full action code include the return statement?

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Razor Syntax allows you to output a variable in html/javascript by just doing  '@donutSerialized'.

Comment: OK - So all this code is inside a razor view, thanks. Try @Html.Raw(@donutSerialized)

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer That fixed it! Does Razor automatically try to encode everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything generated from C# will be HTML encoded by Razor by default.

So when you do @methodCall() it will be encoded.

If you want the value to stay as is, you can use @Html.Raw(@methodCall()).

Here is a quick link to a cheat sheet by Phil Haack - http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: Thanks for the link to Phil's cheat sheet. Makes it a lot clearer.